# How to filter (show/hide) Owl Carousel 2 items (images) based on selected variant with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, owl-carousel-2

I want to hide or show the images in the owl carousel slide according to the selected variants.

When a variant is selected, I want only images related to that variant to remain in the owl carousel.

When another variant is selected, I want to hide the others and show images of the newly selected variant.

For this, I added data-variant information to the div elements and tried to change them accordingly. But when there is a selection, all images disappear.

This is my owl carousel HTML code.

```
<div class="thumb-gallery-wrapper">
 <div class="thumb-gallery-detail owl-carousel owl-theme manual nav-inside nav-style-1 nav-dark nav-arrows-thin mb-3">
  <div data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div data-variant="variant 2"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div data-variant="variant 2"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  ...
 </div>
 
 <div class="thumb-gallery-thumbs owl-carousel owl-theme manual mb-0">
  <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 2"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 2"><img alt="" src="" /></div>
  ...
 </div>
</div>
```

This is template's owl carousel code:

```
(function ($) {

 'use strict';
 
 theme.fn.intObs('.thumb-gallery-wrapper', function () {
  var $thumbGalleryDetail = $(this).find('.thumb-gallery-detail'),
   $thumbGalleryThumbs = $(this).find('.thumb-gallery-thumbs'),
   flag = false,
   duration = 300;

  $thumbGalleryDetail
   .owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    dots: false,
    loop: false,
    autoHeight: true,
    navText: [],
    rtl: ($('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl') ? true : false
   })
   .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
    if (!flag) {
     flag = true;
     $thumbGalleryThumbs.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index - 1, duration, true]);

     $thumbGalleryThumbs.find('.owl-item').removeClass('selected');
     $thumbGalleryThumbs.find('.owl-item').eq(e.item.index).addClass('selected');
     flag = false;
    }
   });

  $thumbGalleryThumbs
   .owlCarousel({
    margin: 15,
    items: $(this).data('thumbs-items') ? $(this).data('thumbs-items') : 4,
    nav: false,
    center: $(this).data('thumbs-center') ? true : false,
    dots: false,
    rtl: ($('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl') ? true : false
   })
   .on('click', '.owl-item', function () {
    $thumbGalleryDetail.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), duration, true]);
   })
   .on('changed.owl.carousel', function (e) {
    if (!flag) {
     flag = true;
     $thumbGalleryDetail.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [e.item.index, duration, true]);
     flag = false;
    }
   });

  $thumbGalleryThumbs.find('.owl-item').eq(0).addClass('selected');
 }, {});

}).apply(this, [jQuery]);
```

My filter function below, triggered by button or selection, hides the entire gallery.

```
var variantToShow = 'variant 1';

$('.thumb-gallery-wrapper').each(function () {
  var $thumbGalleryDetail = $(this).find('.thumb-gallery-detail'),
      $thumbGalleryThumbs = $(this).find('.thumb-gallery-thumbs');

  $thumbGalleryDetail.find('div:not([data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"])').parent().hide();
  $thumbGalleryDetail.find('div[data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"]').parent().show();
  $thumbGalleryDetail.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');

  $thumbGalleryThumbs.find('div:not([data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"])').parent().hide();
  $thumbGalleryThumbs.find('div[data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"]').parent().show();
  $thumbGalleryThumbs.trigger('refresh.owl.carousel');
});
```

Here is the result:

```
<div class="thumb-gallery-wrapper">
    <div
        class="thumb-gallery-detail owl-carousel owl-theme manual nav-inside nav-style-1 nav-dark nav-arrows-thin mb-3 owl-loaded owl-drag">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer owl-height" style="height: 0px; display: none;">
            <div class="owl-stage"
                style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 2766px; display: none;">
                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 1" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: -171.839px -646.317px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;); top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 1" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: 0px 0px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; display: none; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 2" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: 0px 0px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; display: none; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: 0px 0px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; display: none; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: 0px 0px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; display: none; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 451px; margin-right: 10px; display: none;">
                    <div data-variant="variant 2" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid lazyload" src="" data-zoom-image="">
                        <div class="zoomContainer" style="transform: translateZ(0px); position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 253.683px; width: 451px; display: none;">
                            <div class="zoomWindowContainer" style="width: 400px; display: none;">
                                <div style="z-index: 999; overflow: hidden; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; background-position: 0px 0px; width: 451px; height: 253.683px; float: left; display: none; cursor: grab; background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; background-image: url(&quot;https://...webp&quot;);" class="zoomWindow">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-nav" style="display: none;">
            <button type="button" role="presentation" aria-label="nav" class="owl-prev disabled"></button>
            <button type="button" role="presentation" aria-label="nav" class="owl-next"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-dots disabled" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="thumb-gallery-thumbs owl-carousel owl-theme manual mb-0 owl-loaded owl-drag">
        <div class="owl-stage-outer" style="display: none;">
            <div class="owl-stage" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); transition: all 0s ease 0s; width: 699px; display: none;">
                <div class="owl-item selected active" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 2" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item active" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 1"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="owl-item" style="width: 101.5px; margin-right: 15px; display: none;">
                    <div class="cur-pointer" data-variant="variant 2" style="display: none;"><img alt="" class="img-fluid ls-is-cached lazyloaded" src=""></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-nav disabled" style="display: none;">
            <button type="button" role="presentation" aria-label="nav" class="owl-prev"><span aria-label="Previous">‹</span></button>
            <button type="button" role="presentation" aria-label="nav" class="owl-next"><span aria-label="Next">›</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-dots disabled" style="display: none;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code, by selecting the parent of any matched div, will hide the entire thumb-gallery-thumbs element which will by extension hides all elements within it.  You have an unnecessary call to parent() in this line of code:

```
$thumbGalleryDetail.find('div:not([data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"])').parent().hide();
```

I think what you want is this:

```
$thumbGalleryDetail.find('div:not([data-variant="' + variantToShow + '"])').hide();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I've already tried this, and unfortunately, it's not working either.